# What's the constant $K$ here for?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Im studying in the 10th grade and i have this problem understanding why is there the constant $K$ in the following.

We are studying the relationships between the zeroes of the polynomial and we have this section on find the polynomial from the given zeroes.

Let's say $p$ and $q$ are two zeroes then we know that

$$K[x^2 - (\mathrm{sum \; of \; the \; zeroes \; i.e.} \; p+q)x - (\mathrm{Constant \; term \; i.e.} \; pq)]$$ Where $K$ is a constant.

Why is the constant $K$ here I can't figure that out?

Comment: Multiplying the entire function by k does not change the location of the zeroes!  knowing that f(p) = 0 = f(q) just means that f(x) is divisible by $(x-p)(x-q)$.  If you know that f(x) has degree 2 then that means that the quotient has degree 0, hence is a constant, k, so $f(x) = k(x-p)(x-q)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant $K$ is there because $x^2-(p+q)x-pq$ and $2x^2-2(p+q)x-2pq$ both have the same roots, namely $p$ and $q$. In fact, for any $K \neq 0$, we have that $$Kx^2-K(p+q)x-Kpq$$

has the same roots as $x^2-(p+q)x-pq$. This can be seen by dividing both sides in $Kx^2-K(p+q)x-Kpq=0$ by $K$. This obviously gives $x^2-(p+q)x-pq=0$.

Answer (score 0):

It should be $k(x^2-(p+q)x + pq)$ or in a better form $k(x-q)(x-p)$ the Constant $k$ will not change the zeros so for generality it is put in.